# Is there anyway to create an 'await' function in javascript that block on Q.js promise until the value is redeemed?

Tags: javascript, promise, q

I know JS is a mono-threaded environment but is there a way to create a 'await' function that block on Q.js promise until the value is redeemed ?

Of course, the following code will end to an infinite loop.
Because of the 'while', the 'setTimeout' callback is never called and 'isFulfilled' function returns always 'false' value.

```
var d = Q.defer();
window.setTimeout(function() {
  d.resolve(true);
}, 1000);
await(d.promise);

function await(p) {
    var value = undefined;
    while(value == undefined) {
        if(p.isFulfilled()) {
            return p.inspect().value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No but what are you trying to do

Comment: Does the promise object not have a `then`, i.e: `d.promise.then(function(){//execute when promise is returned})`? It seems to mention it on the [**github page**](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) in the readme on the main page. It seems to also have a `done()` method.

Comment: I want to be able to get ride of the promise in order make a recursive  function 'tailrec'

Comment: You could try a [waitfor](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/run-jasmine.js) work pattern similar to headless js testing.

Comment: 'waitFor' doesn't seem to block.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can yield with `Q.async`. Note it will only block the current chain. Moreover, it requires generator support so it'll only work in NodeJS under a flag, or with the traceur ES6-> ES3/5 compiler since it uses a new language feature:

```
Q.async(function* (){
    console.log("Hello"); 
    var value = yield (new Q.Promise(function(r){ setTimeout(r,1000); }));
    // alternatively, and more correctly: var value = Q(true).delay(1000);
    console.log("World"); // will log one second later.
});
```

The `yield` keyword is used as `await`, in ES7, async/await will finally have language support in JavaScript.

It's worth mentioning, better/newer promise libraries like Bluebird implement generators much faster, so fast in fact - [that they even beat callbacks in performance.](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/50a142a9044c77926074c206c1794b9ab2a09c31/benchmark/stats/latest.md)

Comment: But actually blocking on promise would be useful in some cases, like loading configuration at server startup. That gives me an idea for a native extension, seems nobody has done it :P

Comment: @Esailija Actually blocking is not what `await` would do here either. Not sure I understand "loading configuration at server startup" or why that should be sync (although I guess it should and it doesn't really matter, since no one ever would think to do something absurd like restart their server whenever they get any error in Node) :P

Comment: I know await doesn't block here that's why I brought up that actually blocking is useful for e.g. loading configuration at server startup